# Method returns one or more, should it return an Array when there is only one item?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

Let's say we have a Ruby method like this:

```
# Pseudocode
def get(globbed)
  a_items = Dir.glob(globbed)
  a_items.length == 1 ? a_items.first : a_items
end
```

The method is meant to return a String containing information about the `items` in question. If there are many items, it will return an Array. The ternary makes it so that if there is only one item, it just returns that String.

What is the best practice here? Should such a method always return an Array even if there is only one item?

Comment: Why do you want to complicate the API returning different types depending on the arguments of a function? Then whenever people call that function they must check what was returned. (There are some `numpy`/`scipy` functions that do that and using them is a pain...)

Comment: Good question. I have no idea. ;) Thanks.

Comment: Even if the result is empty, I would return an empty array instead of `nil` or something so that the caller can always expect an array.

Comment: Actually because a lot of the time I'll be using the method to get just one thing and I'll always have to do something like Array.first. Maybe I'll just have two methods. One for getting one item and another that supports Globbing and always returns an Array.

Comment: I ended up happy with my approach. The `get` method I wrote always returns an array. To help with situations where I expect to get just one item, I have `get_one` that calls `get` with the same arguments and returns the first item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should always return an array. Returning different things means that whatever method that calls this method would also have to have a condition. That is not good. Whenever you can get rid of a condition, you should. A condition should only be used as a last resort.

As a real example, the jQuery library built on top of JavaScript has the notion of selectors, expressed in the form `$(...)`. This can result in multiple matching dom objects, or a single one. But jQuery always returns an array even if the matched dom object is one. That makes things simple.

Answer (score 0):

It's always about use cases. You have to define what's the responsibility of that method and then decide what makes sense to do.
In this specific case, I would say that, unless there isn't any specific reason to return different types, you should choose the way that is simpler, both to test and to read.
Always returning an array in this case means clearer method interface:

> "The method returns an array with the directory content"

instead of the more convoluted

> "The method returns an array of directory content if there more than
>   one object, otherwise return the single object."

So, clarity first of all.
And: testing would result easier. The [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) of the routine is less.

There are cases where the uniformity of return types can't be fulfilled. Just think of the [Array method `index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-index): it wouldn't be possible to distinguish between "object not found" and "index 0" if the practice here was applied.

Conclusion: here I don't see any reason why to make the method more complex by distinguishing the two cases, so.. [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Answer (score 0):

Hi, ruby provides block, yield and iterator to permit easy array or hash treatment. And it's a good practice to use the same code for one or several numbers of element. Exemple :

a_items.each { |element| file_treatment(element) }

Regards.